# limit Zoom meetings with max participants

Tags: api, zoom-sdk

Is there a way to create a zoom meeting for a specific max number of participants?

For example,

If a player books a "Small" package, which is up to 6 players, is it possible to create a zoom link for 7 players max (1 host + 6 players)?

If a player books a "Mid" package, which is up to 8 players, is it possible to create a zoom link for 9 players max (1 host + 8 players)?

If a player books a "Large" package, which is up to 10 players, is it possible to create a zoom link for 11 players max (1 host + 10 players)?

If a player books a "XL" package, which is for a custom number of players, is it possible to create a zoom link for that specific amount of players + 1 host?

then how can i limit number of participants who join zoom meeting

Is it can be done using Zoom API

```
    let createZoomMeeting = (req, res, next, meetingoption) => {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
        if (meetingoption) {
            const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
            const payload = {
                iss: ZOOM_API_KEY,
                exp: ((new Date()).getTime() + 5000)
            };
            const token = jwt.sign(payload, ZOOM_API_SECRET);

            let optionsForHost = {
                conditions: {
                    user_role_id: FRONT_USER_ROLE_ID,
                    active: ACTIVE,
                    is_deleted: NOT_DELETED,
                    is_verified: VERIFIED,
                },
                fields: {
                    _id: 1, full_name: 1, email: 1,
                }
            };
            /**Condition for player Slug*/
            optionsForHost.conditions._id = meetingoption.host_id;
            /** Get host details **/
            let hostResponse = await getUserData(req, res, next, optionsForHost);
            /** get global zoom url and set email for particular host **/
            let HOST_ZOOM_URL = MEETING_ZOOM_URL;
            const host_email = hostResponse.result.email ? hostResponse.result.email : "hello@gamenitesocial.com";
            HOST_ZOOM_URL = HOST_ZOOM_URL.replace("me", host_email);

            if (hostResponse.status != STATUS_SUCCESS) return next(hostResponse.message);
            if (!hostResponse.result) return resolve({ status: STATUS_ERROR, message: res.__("admin.system.invalid_access") });

            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: HOST_ZOOM_URL,
                headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json', authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
                body: {
                    topic: meetingoption.game_type + ' (' + meetingoption.game_name + '-' + meetingoption.game_category_name + ')',
                    type: 2,
                    start_time: meetingoption.game_date + 'T' + meetingoption.start_time + ":00:00",
                    timezone: 'America/New_York',
                    agenda: meetingoption.game_type + ' (' + meetingoption.game_name + '-' + meetingoption.game_category_name + ')',
                    settings: {
                        host_video: true,
                        participant_video: true,
                        join_before_host: false,
                        mute_upon_entry: true,
                        use_pmi: false,
                        approval_type: 2,
                        alternative_hosts: hostResponse.result.email
                    }
                },
                json: true
            };

            request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) throw new Error(error);

                return resolve({ status: STATUS_SUCCESS, result: body });
            });
        } else {
            return resolve({ status: STATUS_ERROR, result: {} });
        }
    });
};// End createZoomMeeting().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this by zoom/SDK zoom SDK does not provide such type of parameter in its documentation

Reference Link: [Create Zoom meeting Docs Link](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/methods#operation/meetingCreate)